# JQuery find loaded element by id or other

Tags: jquery

I have a button that loads the following table in a div:

```html
<table id="id_table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Code</th>
   <th>Description</th>
   <th>Group</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th><input type="text" id="txtcolumn1"/></th>
   <th><input type="text" id="txtcolumn2"/></th>
   <th><input type="text" id="txtcolumn3"/></th>
  </tr>            
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr data="line1">
   <td data="column1">001.01-A</td>
   <td data="column2">Black bean</td>
   <td data="column3">Cereal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data="line2">
   <td data="column1">001.02-B</td>
   <td data="column2">White bean</td>
   <td data="column3">Cereal</td>
  </tr>            
  <tr data="line3">
   <td data="column1">002.10-C</td>
   <td data="column2">Rice</td>
   <td data="column3">Cereal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data="line4">
   <td data="column1">047.27-D</td>
   <td data="column2">Soap</td>
   <td data="column3">Cleaning</td>
  </tr>            
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I will use the inputs to filter the table content and show only the colmuns that matches with the value typed on each input after the table is loaded. To filter the table I'm using the event 'keyup' as follows:

```js
$("#id_div_Content").on('keyup','#id_table input',function(){
 var indice = $(this).parent().index()+1;
 var valor = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
 $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('tr').show();
 
 $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('td').each(function(){
  var coluna = $(this).attr('data');
  if (coluna == "coluna" + indice.toString()) {
      if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(valor) < 0){
       $(this).parent().hide();
      }
     }
 });
});
```

My doubt is: inside this 'keyup' event, how can I find the elements of the table by data, id or any else? JQuery cannot find this elements just using direct selectors, because it's a loaded html in a div after a button click.

I got it using $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent() to reach the table id (for example) from the input, but this is just a small test and in the final version of the page things will be much more complex. I will have more tables and fields and that way I may need a mile of .parent() to reach the elements.

Thanks since now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use normal selectors in that keyup handler.  Since your doing a delegate binding, when that processes the element will exist in the dom at that point.  So you can look them up normally.

I might suggest making "column1", "column2", and "column3" classes instead of data elements though if you wish to select by them.

Edit:
Aside from that, `data="value"` is not typically how you use data elements.  Typically they follow the pattern of `data-key="value"` and then later you reference them with `data('key')` and `data('key', newValue)`

Comment: I don't know which was my error, but I tried it before in many ways and never worked. Now I tried and it's working. Anyway, thanks!